# Likelihood Estimation from Transfer Function

Tags: dynamical-systems, maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter

Given a sequence of observations presumed to be produced by an autonomous linear dynamical system, is it possible (and if so how) to determine the likelihood of the sequence without inferring the state space parameters?

My thought was to consider the likelihood of a sequence produced by a transfer function - but I'm not sure if this is possible. I know I can infer the state space parameters and then use a Kalman filter, but ideally I avoid this step.

My particular use case is to learn a encoding/decoding function of observations which in their encoded form could have been produced by an autonomous linear dynamical system. I don't particularly care about the state space parameters while learning the encoding function, and I'm hoping that I can take advantage of this and reduce the computational load during training.

Comment: With autonomous linear dynamical system you mean something like $x_{k+1}=A\,x_k,\quad y_k=C\,x_k$ with $y_k$ the observed variable? Also do you assume that there are input and output disturbances acting on it?

Comment: Yes - exactly that. As for disturbances, it wouldn't be strictly necessary - but I suspect that any "likelihood" formulation will require state and observation measurements to be random variables and so Gaussian noise probably makes sense.

Comment: But $A$ and $C$ are unknown, right? So you would have to estimate those along with the state simultaneously, or can you estimate the matrices beforehand?

Comment: In the state space model, yes, they are unknown. But there are many A and C matricies that can produce the same observation sequence - the transfer function describes the whole set of A and C... by computing the likelihood in the frequency domain, we avoid having to (unnessesarily) pick a single A and C.

Comment: To some degree, imagine that I showed you a plot of a univariate $y_t$ from unknown A and C... if you have a lot of experience with linear systems, you might be able to recognize that $y_t$ definitely came from a linear system, or maybe you say "it's _almost_ linear". if the sequence definitely came from a linear system, it would have maximum likelihood. If you could (instead) project the sequence of $y_t$ to the nearest linear trajectory, the error between trajectories would be related to the likelihood that the sequence $y_t$ came from some linear system described by an unknown A and C.

Comment: Without disturbances you can also rewrite the state space as a difference equation $y_k=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\,y_{k-i}$. You can also add a disturbance $e_k$, but $e_i$ and $e_j$ whith $i \neq j$ can be correlated.